# If too many players wins the game, can the Boss and Profiteer win no gold?

Tags: saboteur-2

If 5 players wins the game (2 green dwarfs, 1 blue dwarf, a Boss and a Profiteer), they only get 1 gold piece each. But the Boss gets 1 less, and the Profiteer gets 2 less. That means that they get no gold piece at all?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Part of the game is knowing when not to end the game. In the scenario you described, the Boss or the Profiteer must have ended the game (because it's the only way a Green and a Blue can both win with those characters). But that might not have been their best option.

The following is the scoring possibilities for the party you presented:

```
           There's   There's |         |          
  Game     a Blue    a Green | Winners | Nuggets    Green     Blue      Boss    Profiteer
  Ender     Path      Path   |         |          
--------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
Green         Y         Y    |    4    |    2         2         0         1         0
Blue          Y         Y    |    3    |    3         0         3         2         1
Boss          Y         Y    |    5    |    1         1         1         0         0
Profiteer     Y         Y    |    5    |    1         1         1         0         0
Anyone        Y         N    |    3    |    3         0         3         2         1
Anyone        N         Y    |    4    |    2         2         0         1         0
Noone         N         N    |    1    |    5         0         0         0         3
```

For the most points, the Boss should have joined the Blue team (by blocking green or by enabling Blue to end) rather than ending the game. Joining Green would also grant some points.

For the most points, the Profiteer should have sabotaged the miners rather than end the game. Helping Blue would also net some rewards.